# ExceptionInInitializerError when using AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am using an AsyncTask to read data from a file. I get the aforementioned error when I run the application.

The error messages are:

> 03-29 20:06:08.445: E/AndroidRuntime(13191):
>   java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError 03-29 20:06:08.445:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(13191):
>       at
>   com.google.app.BouncingBall.HighScore.loadFromFile(HighScore.java:81)
>   03-29 20:06:08.445: E/AndroidRuntime(13191):
>       at
>   com.google.app.BouncingBall.HighScore.(HighScore.java:24) 03-29
>   20:06:08.445: E/AndroidRuntime(13191):    at
>   com.google.app.BouncingBall.BouncingBallActivity$BouncingBallView.init(BouncingBallActivity.java:185)
>   03-29 20:06:08.445: E/AndroidRuntime(13191):  at
>   com.google.app.BouncingBall.BouncingBallActivity$BouncingBallView.run(BouncingBallActivity.java:173)
>   03-29 20:06:08.445: E/AndroidRuntime(13191):  at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019) 03-29 20:06:08.445:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(13191): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't
>   create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
>   03-29 20:06:08.445: E/AndroidRuntime(13191):  at
>   android.os.Handler.(Handler.java:121)

The Code

```
private void loadFromFile()
    {
        new AsyncDataStorage().execute(FILENAME);
    }


class AsyncDataStorage extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Boolean> {

        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... args) {
            try {
                FileInputStream fis = context.openFileInput(FILENAME);
                byte[]  raw = new byte[fis.available()];
                String rawData=null;
                while(fis.read()!=-1)
                {
                    rawData = new String(raw);
                }
                return (processRawData(rawData));
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }

        }
```

Comment: Simply wrap every call to `com.google.app.BouncingBall.HighScore.loadFromFile` or the creation of AsyncTask within it in a Runnable, and post it to a Handler bound to the UI thread

Comment: That worked. Could you please write write that as Answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply wrap every call to `com.google.app.BouncingBall.HighScore.loadFromFile` or the creation of `AsyncTask` within it in a Runnable, and post it to a Handler bound to the UI thread.

Answer (score 13):

```
03-29 20:06:08.445: E/AndroidRuntime(13191): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare() 03-29 20:06:08.445:
```

Quoting [the documentation for `AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html):

> The task instance must be created on the UI thread.

In your cask, the task instance is not being created on the main application (a.k.a., UI) thread, which is what leads to this exception.

Comment: Thank you Sir! just simple and understandable explanation.

Comment: Does the ExceptionInInitializerError exception occur ONLY when creating the AsyncTask in another thread? Or can it occur on other cases too? I know the logs here show the reason is what you wrote, but I have another ExceptionInInitializerError that doesn't show it.

Comment: @androiddeveloper: I have no idea -- check the source code.